# Reference help - Linear Algebra and Calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I went through some of the questions asking for reference help but they're not the same (definitely similar though). Maybe i missed something but here goes-

I know there are Gilbert Strang videos, textbooks and other sources that are similar to learn Linear Algebra but what i want to know is - are there any **concise** (preferably freely available) text books to **review** the concepts? I say review because I've taken up both Linear Algebra and Calculus 6-7 years ago and they are rusty.

I need to review these for grad school and I'm short of time to re-learn everything from scratch.

I need to brush up the **basics** for example,

**Linear Algebra** -

- Vectors, and solving linear equations
- Spaces
- Matrices (Rank, Row/Column operations)
- Determinants
- Eigen values and Eigen vectors.

**Calculus**

- Limits (and some pre-calculus)
- solving differential equations (ODEs and PDEs et al)
- basic integral calculus

What I'm looking for is **review** sources and **primers** that maybe some of you have found really useful.

**Edit** - Some very helpful links, thank you all. I also found [PatrickJMT.com](http://PatrickJMT.com) for very basic stuff to solve a few problems and help remember high school learning. And some wandering soul might appreciate this link as well - [Additional Resources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/what-is-a-good-book-to-study-linear-algebra)

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but have you tried looking thru Pauls Online Math Notes

Comment: you could try is to search for free online lecture notes from some university.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that anytime I needed to review a topic, I searched lecture/class notes.
Here are a few resources that may be of use for you:

[Linear algebra/Analysis and Calculus review](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/ee227a/review_lecture_one.pdf) (Berkeley lecture notes)

[Review of Linear Algebra and 
Vector Calculus](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~xfern/classes/cs534/notes/LAVC-review.pdf) (Slides adapted from notes by Andrew Rosenberg)

[Paul's Online Maths Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/)

[Links to several relevant topic reviews, practice questions and answers](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-008-calculus-revisited-complex-variables-differential-equations-and-linear-algebra-fall-2011/study-materials/) from MIT - it is important to test yourself as you review.

Good luck with grad school!

Comment: Wow! I appreciate the links; especially the fourth one. The courseware is pretty concise too. Thank you.

Thank you as well as @Kainui for recommending the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note -- if you are in a hurry I recommend against Strang's book.  I found it nearly impossible to read -- and I already knew the material.

Comment: I agree. While very engaging, it does not serve one's purpose of getting a good and quick review.

Comment: To which Strang book are you referring? I tend to agree on the introductory linear algebra book, but I haven't read his more advanced linear algebra book.

Comment: yes, the introductory book -- I haven't read any other linear algebra book by him

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Herb Gross's "Calculus Revisited" playlist from either MIT or Youtube. He is incredible and has done videos for linear algebra and differential equations.

Here's a quick google link I found, but I think he covers more than what's presented there.

http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-008-calculus-revisited-complex-variables-differential-equations-and-linear-algebra-fall-2011/