# Recommendation for study of Linear Algebra Through Geometry (Wermer-Banchoff)

Tags: book-recommendation

I want to self-study Banchoff-Wermer's book over the summer. I will take Analytic Geometry and Linear Algebra course this semester. We will use Wermer-Banchoff's book Linear Algebra Through Geometry. I viewed this book but I don't have enough information about this book.

Can you give me suggestion for self-study this book? What should be prerequisites for study of the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the preface to the book, which you can (usually) see [on Amazon,](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Through-Geometry-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387975861)

> "Except for Chapter 8, the student need only know basic high-school algebra and geometry and introductory trigonometry in order to read this book. In fact, we believe that high-school seniors who are interested in mathematics could read much of this book on their own. To read Chapter 8, students should have a knowledge of elementary calculus."

For the record, the book has some mixed reviews on Amazon (which you might want to read).

For what it's worth, in principle I think I agree with the book's overall approach, but it might be tricky to pull-off. Be sure to use other study sources (good advice in any regard), which you can find, for example, [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804716/very-good-linear-algebra-book) In particular I recommend the books by Strang and the book by Hefferon for a first course.