# To show $W= \big((x,y,z)| \ \ ax+by+cz=0 ; x,y,z\in F\big) $ is a subspace of $V_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $a,b,c $ be a fix elements of a field $F$ Show that $$W= \big((x,y,z)| \ \ ax+by+cz=0 ; x,y,z\in F\big) $$ is a subspace of $V_3(F)$

The necessary and sufficient condition for non empty subset $W$ of a vector space $V(F)$ to be a subspace of V is that $\alpha u+\beta v\in W $ for all $\alpha ,\beta\in F$ and $u,v\in W$

Now in this question I used above thought and proceeded in following manner.

Let $u=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$

$v=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$

$\alpha u+\beta v = \alpha(x_1,y_1,z_1)+ \beta(x_2,y_2,z_2)$

$\implies(\alpha x_1 +\beta x_2,\alpha y_1+\beta y_2,\alpha z_1+\beta z_2)$

Now can I say $(\alpha x_1 +\beta x_2,\alpha y_1+\beta y_2,\alpha z_1+\beta z_2)\in W  \implies \alpha u+\beta v \in W $ ??

Did I do it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to verify that $\alpha u + \beta v \in W$ rather than just claiming that it is in $W$.

Verify that $a(\alpha x_1+\beta x_2) + b (\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2)+ c( \alpha z_1 +\beta z_2)$ is equal to zero.

Also remember to check that $W$ is non-empty and closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Why do we have to show it is equal to zero ? Because of this condition $ax+by+cz=0$?

Comment: yup, that is how you verify an element is in $W$. and of course we have $\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 \in F$, similarly for $y$ and $z$.

Comment: And how to check W is non empty?

Comment: $(0,0,0) \in W $ making it non empty set right?

Comment: congratulations.

Comment: Haha I just started learning linear algebra. Can you prefer any book for newbie ?

Comment: check out  [references discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/804716/306553).

Answer (score 1):

Let $(l,m,n)=(\alpha x_1 +\beta x_2,\alpha y_1+\beta y_2,\alpha z_1+\beta z_2)$. It is easy to verify that $al+bm+cn=0$. Thus, $(l,m,n)\in W$ which was what was required to be shown.

Comment: Bhai can I contact you I have more doubts.

Comment: @Damn1o1 You can ask your doubts here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies It's a very active room