# Find Minimizer and Minimum Value for a Function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratics

I am trying to work through some problems to find the minimizer and minimum value of a function.  The book I am using doesn't have a clear cut example and I can't seem to find a good example online anywhere, so I have no idea where to begin.  The function I am trying to do this for is 
$$
3x^{2} + 3xy + 3y^{2} - 2x - 2y + 4
$$

The only thing I can find is that we have to rewrite the equation in the following compact matrix notation
$$
p(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{x}^{T}K\textbf{x} - 2\textbf{x}^{T}\textbf{f} + c
$$
where $K = (k_{ij})$ is a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix, $\textbf{f}$ is a constant vector, and $c$ is a constant scalar.  However, it doesn't really explain how to come up with those values.  I'm guessing that in the problem I am trying to work through that $c = 4$ and that $\textbf{x} = [x, y]^{T}$, but I have no idea how to determine $K$ and $\textbf{f}$.

If someone could show me how to find $K$ and $\textbf{f}$ I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspection

$K = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}$

$$
\textbf{x}^{T}K\textbf{x} = a x^2 + 2 b x y + c y^2 = 3 x^2 + 3 x y + 3 y^2
$$

So $K = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 3/2 \\ 3/2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Similarly

$\textbf{f} = \begin{pmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \end{pmatrix}$

$$
-2\textbf{x}^{T}\textbf{f} = -2 f_1 x - 2 f_2 y = -2 x -2 y
$$

Thus $\textbf{f} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Okay, so given $\textbf{x}^{T} = \begin{bmatrix}x & y\end{bmatrix}$ and the quadratic equation $ax^{2} + bxy + cy^{2} + dx + ey + f$ is it safe to say the following?
$$
K = \begin{bmatrix} a & \frac{b}{2} \\ \frac{b}{2} & c \end{bmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad \textbf{f} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{d}{2} \\ -\frac{e}{2} \end{bmatrix} = -\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} d \\ e \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Yes, and it is not only safe, but the only possibility

Comment: Thank you, it would be really helpful if they just put that in the book.

Comment: Indeed, I also learn better by looking at examples. Feel free to browse [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/what-is-a-good-book-to-study-linear-algebra)