# I am wondering which book I should buy to study Linear Algebra from home?

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I am studying from home and I'd like to learn linear algebra on my own.

Is there a good book I should buy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/what-is-a-good-book-to-study-linear-algebra?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612431/book-for-studying-linear-algebra?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454752/a-rigorous-book-on-a-first-course-in-linear-algebra?noredirect=1&lq=1 and others.

Comment: try https://www.amazon.com/Course-Linear-Algebra-Applications-ebook/dp/B005BP1Z4E without any doubt it is good

Comment: Hi: I know how tempting it is just to go to the first forum that seems relevant and blurt your question. But consider that it might be *even faster* to get your answer just do a google search or use the forum's search feature.  It turns out that a lot of the time, someone has asked before (perhaps even more than a handful of times) and gotten lots of good answers.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally liked *Linear Algebra with Applications* by Otto Bretscher. I thought it was a great introduction to the subject with a good balance of theory and practice problems to help. I'm not sure which is the latest version, but I used the 2012 edition.

Answer (score -1):

What's your background in mathematics? If you don't have that much exposure to formal proof-writing, then I recommend "Linear Algebra and its Applications" by David Lay. If you're a bit more mature, I would recommend "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler.