# Good online resource for studying introductory linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, linear-transformations

I'd prefer something like a website or an online pdf.

We haven't started row space or column space or anything, although we've done bases, linear independence, span, matrices as linear transformations, subspaces/vector spaces, and we've defined the dimension of a space, noting that it it's an invariant for the vector space.

Comment: See the online resources given at the answers to [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/what-is-a-good-book-to-study-linear-algebra?rq=1).