# Textbook for first course in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, self-learning

I am looking for a textbook to aid me in self studying linear algebra. I currently own Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, but I fear it is not sufficient for an initial treatment. Any recommendations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good book to study linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/what-is-a-good-book-to-study-linear-algebra).

Comment: in what sense it is not sufficient Axler's book? For your first course in linear algebra Im sure it is very sufficient.

Comment: @Masacroso: There are more things, Horatio. If you haven't learned more linear algebra than is in Axler's book in your undergrad, it is a problem with your education, not with linear algebra.

Comment: @Masacroso: I'm puzzled also. I suspect "not sufficient for an initial treatment" was incorrectly worded, and what was intended was "not sufficiently elementary for an initial treatment".

Comment: To clarify, in regards to my use of the word "sufficient", I meant it with respects to and introduction.

Comment: @DandyYantoid Do you mean that Axler's book is too difficult or that it doesn't have enough depth/rigor/scope?

Answer (score 0):

Gilbert Strang has written I think more than one.

My former advisor Peter Petersen has written one (that I haven't seen).

My undergraduate course at Berkeley was taught by Bill Jacob, whose book was in manuscript form at the time (late 80's).  I liked it.

Howard Anton has a book (at least).

There are, I would guess, numerous such books.